# React-Native download file from server and add to google drive

Tags: react-native

I am using React-Native FS to download pdf file from server and save in local storage. Now I have another requirement to add the file to google drive from server. I have no idea how to setup toFile info for google drive.

Is there a way to add file to google drive from server.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-share solved my problem. Just follow the instruction.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share